# objective c How to map AES from android to iOS

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes

I have to build an iOS application (objective C) that use AES algorithm to encrypt password via internet. 
The Android app and server are done, they are using the code below. But I can't map it to objective C. Please help me!

*** The java code in android:

```
public class AesBase64Wrapper {

    private static String IV = "IV_VALUE_16_BYTE"; 
    private static String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD_VALUE"; 
    private static String SALT = "SALT_VALUE";

    public String encryptAndEncode(String raw) {
        try {
            Cipher c = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
            byte[] encryptedVal = c.doFinal(getBytes(raw));
            String s = getString(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedVal));
            return s;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    }

    private String getString(byte[] bytes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    }

    private byte[] getBytes(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return str.getBytes("UTF-8");
    }

    private Cipher getCipher(int mode) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] iv = getBytes(IV);
        c.init(mode, generateKey(), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return c;
    }

    private Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        char[] password = PASSWORD.toCharArray();
        byte[] salt = getBytes(SALT);

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 2048, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        byte[] encoded = tmp.getEncoded();
        return new SecretKeySpec(encoded, "AES");
    }
}
```

*** My objective C code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *testRawPass = @"12345678aA@";
    NSData *testIV = [@"IV_VALUE_16_BYTE" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *testSecret = @"PASSWORD_VALUE";
    NSString *saltValue = @"SALT_VALUE";

    NSString *key = [self generateKey:testSecret salt:saltValue];
    NSString *testEncryptedPass = [CryptUtils encryptAES256WithString:testRawPass withKey:key withIV:testIV];

    NSLog(@" ********* testEncryptedPass = %@", testEncryptedPass);
}

-(NSString*) generateKey:(NSString*)key salt:(NSString*)saltIn {
    int dkLen = 16;
    NSData *keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *salt    = [saltIn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    uint    rounds  = 2048;
    uint    keySize = 128;

    NSMutableData *derivedKey = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:keySize];

    CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(kCCPBKDF2,               // algorithm
                         keyData.bytes,           // password
                         keyData.length,          // passwordLength
                         salt.bytes,              // salt
                         salt.length,             // saltLen
                         kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1,       // PRF
                         rounds,                  // rounds
                         derivedKey.mutableBytes, // derivedKey
                         dkLen*8);                // derivedKeyLen
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:derivedKey encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

and the function encryptAES256withString in my class CryptUtils:

```
+ (NSData *)encryptAES256WithData:(NSData *)data withKey:(NSString *)key withIV:(NSData *)ivdata
{
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char cIv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    bzero(cIv, kCCBlockSizeAES128);
    if (ivdata) {
        [ivdata getBytes:cIv length:kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          cIv /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [data bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted );
    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: but the output is not equal to android function one :(

Answer (score 0):

Android uses a 128-bit key, ObjC uses a 256-bit key. Make the encryption keys the same.

Inspect all input and output values in hex and compare between the two implementations.

Comment: how to modify it? I used uint    keySize = 128; :(

Comment: 'kCCKeySizeAES256' to `kCCKeySizeAES128`. If your understanding of cryptograply is limited it would be best to use a complete cross-platform sulution such as [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor).